How do I change the color of a texture in a specific face?
How to change the color of a texture in a different face of my model (keeping the same texture file)?
I'm trying to make this "cardboard cutout" type of style, using two faces with the same texture in it and making the back one black. But I couldn't find any information online about it.
I want to use the same image texture file because I will animate the textures and I don't want to make just a black version of every texture and use a different material, but everything I find is related to materials and not textures.


Is this for a game (are you exporting this asset elsewhere) or just for use within Blender?

You can make two materials, one which uses the color of the image, one which uses black, both of which use the same alpha channel from the texture. Then you can apply these different materials to the different faces:

A single mesh with two faces (side-by-side here for simplicity of seeing).

Apply a material to the object with an image as alpha:


Note that I have the same UVs on both faces (it looks like you do, too):



Select the object, enter edit mode (Tab) and select one of the faces, then click the + button in the Material to Add Material Slot. Then click the Assign button to assign the selected face to that new material slot, select your existing material, and then click the two-papers icon to make a copy of that material:

In the Shader Editor you can now disconnect the color channel from the image for this new material, and pick a new color like Black:

...or you can tint the existing color of the image using something like a mix color node:


If your shader is more complicated than a single texture, you can create a Node Group out of the complex stuff...

...and then use that in your various materials:


If you have two objects with two faces, it's even easier; no need to create a second material slot, just apply different images to the two objects.
